# Attaching a file with attachfile2 does not work in macOS Preview

Tags: attachfile

Attaching a file with [attachfile2](https://ctan.org/pkg/attachfile2) and the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{attachfile2}

\begin{document}
     \attachfile{test.txt}
\end{document}
```

generates a .pdf-file, which can be opened with [macOS Preview](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/preview/welcome/mac) (Version 11.0). However, clicking or double clicking on the shown PushPin does nothing. Opening the same document with Adobe Reader or Firefox, it works as expected.

Further information:

- Hardware: MacBookPro M1 (macOS Sonoma 14.2.1)
- IDE: PyCharm (2023.3.3) with [TeXiFy](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9473-texify-idea)-Plugin (0.9.3)
- Compiler: pdfLaTeX
- LaTeX Distribution: TeX Live

Any suggestion on how to attach files that can be opened with macOS Preview?

Comment: according to a sister stackexchange site preview does not support attachments so there is nothing you can do from latex to make it work https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/221914

Comment: I assume also embedding files don't work then. Setting up a server, store the files online and link them seems a little bit of an overkill. So hoping for future releases of macOS Preview where this is included is the way to go then... Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a mac, and that answer is rather old so things may have changed, but I doubt it. But you might want to wait for a mac user to post an answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do have a mac and can confirm it still doesn't work (macOS Sonoma)

Comment: Previewers based on Apple's PDFKit don't support the functionality, so neither Preview nor Skim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a sister stackexchange site preview does not support attachments so there is nothing you can do from latex to make it work https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/221914

egreg and Joseph have confirmed this is still the case on current systems.